# Silverstripe: Many to many relation to same class

Tags: orm, many-to-many, silverstripe

I have a class "performance", and to each performance other performances can be linked as recommendations. After some trial and error I have something semi-working, using the ORM:

```
public static $many_many = array(
    'Recommendations'       => 'Performance'
);

public static $belongs_many_many = array(
    'Recommendations'       => 'Performance'
);
```

The above lets me specify recommendations, but in normal many to manies (between two classes), the relation the other way around is also available. Here it is not. Any clue on how to make the inverse relation visible on the "Performance" class without creating the inverse many-to-many and manually inserting the inverse relation there?

Update(May 22, 2014): For now I've come to the conclusion that there isn't an out of the box solution to this problem. I made the following minimal example, based on @FinBoWa's solution, and that shows the "Inverse component of Degree.InterestingDegreesReversed not found (Degree)":

```
class Degree extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        "Name"  => "Varchar(255)",
    );

    private static $many_many = array(
        'InterestingDegrees' => 'Degree'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'InterestingDegreesReversed' => 'Degree.InterestingDegrees'
    );

}

class DegreeAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    public static $managed_models       = array('Degree'); 
    static $url_segment                 = 'degrees'; 
    static $menu_title                  = 'Degrees';
}
```

I also tried @g4b0's solution, but that has the serious drawback that it does not show the reverse relationship in the admin. For now I am using his solution, but it is not a real solution to the problem. Therefore I will not accept an answer for now...

Comment: did you found a real solution for that? I have the same problem

Comment: No, sorry... I worked around it...

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the dot notation in the relations.

One of our projects had degrees and we wanted to relate the interesting degrees using the same class:

```
private static $many_many = array(
    'InterestingDegrees' => 'Degree'
);

private static $belongs_many_many = array(
    'InterestingDegreesReversed' => 'Degree.InterestingDegrees'
);
```

This works if you add the editor manually when relating site trees.

But if you use model admin, you have to declare the fields manually otherwise you will get erros. So a working example if you are using model admin would be:

```
class Degree extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        "Name"  => "Varchar(255)",
    );

    private static $many_many = array(
        'InterestingDegrees' => 'Degree'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'InterestingDegreesReversed' => 'Degree.InterestingDegrees'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields =  new FieldList();

        $fields->add(new TextField("Name"));

        // dont show the field untill we have something to relate to 
        if($this->ID){
            //Interesting degrees
            $gfc = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
            //Remove add and edit features
            $gfc->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton');
            $gfc->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldEditButton');
            $gf = new GridField('InterestingDegrees', null, $this->InterestingDegrees(), $gfc);
            $fields->add($gf);
        }
        return $fields;
    }
}

class DegreeAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    public static $managed_models       = array('Degree'); 
    static $url_segment                 = 'degrees'; 
    static $menu_title                  = 'Degrees';
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I already tried this solution, but it resulted in an error: Inverse component of Performance.RecommendationsReversed not found (Performance)

Comment: That absolutely works on 3.1.4 so you must be either running on a different version or neglected to run dev build after featuring it.

Comment: This most definately does not work on 3.1.4 and 3.1.5. I made a minimal object and it gave the same error message. But maybe that is caused by the fact that I am not using the normal page structure. I am solely working with DataObjects: class Degree extends DataObject

Comment: That code of ours is from a production code and it definately works! Ill have a look was there anything more to it

Comment: Ah! I think you are relying model admin to automatically generate the editors so the RELATION it self isn't the issue but the automatic editor generation is causing issues! And in our case we are using sitetree what doesn't try to add the editors automatically.. ill revise my answer to include the editor what we used

Comment: Iv revised my answer with a working and tested sample

Comment: Just hit me that it wont show the reversed relation also if you try to see where x has been related so this is basically same as @g4b0 but that goes trough the automatic scaffolding of the model admin. We had to use the dot syntax for declaring the relations as we had so many so after other relations to same classes that dev build couldn't create necessary helper tables.

Comment: You're example works, but still the reverse relation is invisible. I tried to add this to the getCMSFields(), but then I got the same error again: 

            $gfc = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
            //Remove add and edit features
            $gfc->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton');
            $gfc->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldEditButton');
            $gf = new GridField('InterestingDegreesReversed', null, $this->InterestingDegreesReversed(), $gfc);
            $fields->add($gf);

(Sorry, not sure how to communicate this without changing my question)

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify two different names for many_many and belongs_many_many, so you can access them. For example:

```
public static $many_many = array(
    'RelatedRecommendations' => 'Performance'
);

public static $belongs_many_many = array(
    'Recommendations'        => 'Performance'
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, adding these two results in two tabs in the edit screen, that do not seem to have a relation. I.e. when adding a RelatedRecommendation, a Recommendation is not added.

Comment: The above code works for me, if I add a RelatedRecommendation (A) to  a Existing Performance (B) then I can see B in the Recommendations of A. Just try to loop over Recommendations and RelatedRecommendations in template. I also suggest you to remove Recommendations tab through removeByName function.

Comment: So programmatically it works, you say. Ok, I'll check that tomorrow. However, I need both tabs, as the relation is not symmetric. 

Any clue on how to do that?

Comment: By the way, how should the ORM know how to relate the two?

Comment: Just try it. In B you will see A in RelatedRecomendations Tab, while in B you will see A in Recomendation Tab. It's up to you to choice if leave both tabs in backend, or remove one of them. In frontend it will simply work as espected.

Comment: Just to be sure: Remember to run the dev/build after amending this that should build the right tables for the orm to hande the relations.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through both ideas, and this is what I've come up with for a project I'm working on (I'm using the `Brand` model).
This is inspired by both solutions, the only additional item I'm adding is the `onAfterWrite` method. There I'm just looping through all brands, and adding the other side.

This takes for all brands to be edited through only the `Brands` tab. The other should be removed in `getCMSFields` like this: `$fields->removeByName('RelatedBrands');`.

```
<?php
class Brand extends DataObject {
    private static $many_many = [
        'Brands' => 'Brand' //part 1 of brand-brand relation
    ];

    private static $belongs_many_many = [
        'RelatedBrands' => 'Brand' //part 2 of brand-brand relation
    ];

    public function onAfterWrite() {
        parent::onAfterWrite();

        foreach ($this->Brands() as $brand) {
            $this->RelatedBrands()->add($brand);
        }
    }
}
```